# Phpfarm dropping zlib from include when adding mysql support

Tags: php, mysql, phpfarm

I have phpfarm compiling php 5.4.21 without error. But when I try to add in support for mysql by adding a custom-options-5.4.21.sh:

```
configoptions="--with-mysql=/usr/"
```

I end up with a failed compile ending with:

```
-L/usr//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcrypt -lresolv -lcrypt -lrt -lmysqlclient -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lcrypt -lxml2 -lxml2 -lxml2 -lcrypt    -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/bin/ld: ext/standard/image.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uncompress'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

It looks like phpfarm is dropping -lz from the linked libraries, but the error is coming from libz.so.1, so does that mean that it is using the zlib library?

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. I had run phpfarm's compile.sh before I had installed libmysqlclient-dev. In the post where I found to install that the post had said to run a make clean. I just assumed phpfarm did that. Turns out, it's in that scipt, but commented out. Went into the php source directory and ran make clean and now it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

i got rid of this error by including --with-zlib in the end of configuration command. here is what i have done:

./configure --with-mysql --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ --with-zlib